# Anaconda: Despite of installing can't import ibm_db

Tags: python, sql, db2

I am able to install `ibm_db`package in order to access DB2 from Jupyter notebook:

```
!pip install ibm_db
Requirement already satisfied: ibm_db in /anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages (2.0.9)
```

but while trying to `import` there's an error:

```
import ibm_db

---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ModuleNotFoundError                       Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-2-fe3bb08c8a05> in <module>()
----> 1 import ibm_db

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'ibm_db'
```

Restarted the Kernel couple of times but it also had no impact.
Anything that I am missing here?

Update:

Was able to resolve the issue by executing the below in Jupyter:

```
!pip uninstall ibm_db
```

and then

```
!conda install ibm_db -c anacharsis
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try installing it using conda instead of pip.  You will probably have to first uninstall the version you added with pip:

```
pip uninstall ibm_db
```

Then install it with conda

```
conda install ibm_db -c anacharsis
```

Comment: Thank you. I just updated my question by adding '!' to the commands.

Answer (score 1):

You need to enter into the environment where you have Python3.7 installed.

Once inside

> > > > pip uninstall ibm_db
> > > >         once ibm_db is uninstalled
> > >
> > > conda install -c conda-forge ibm_db
> > >       This will download and install the packages from Anaconda site

navigate to site-packages- open terminal

> > > > cd /opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages
> > > >         change name for the lib
> > > >         install_name_tool -change libdb2.dylib /opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/clidriver/lib/libdb2.dylib ibm_db.cpython-37m-darwin.so
> >
> > ln -s clidriver/lib/libdb2.dylib libdb2.dylib

Restart terminal and run

> > > import ibm_db

voila!!!